# install PHP 7.2 Mac OS with brew keep showing PHP71

Tags: php, macos, homebrew

I am trying to install PHP 7.2 on my Mac

I did:

```
php --version
```

**PHP 7.1.33 (cli) (built: Jan 26 2020 22:52:32) ( NTS )**

So I started to install the PHP 72

```
brew update
brew upgrade
```

Then I couldnt unlink PHP71

```
brew unlink php71
```

**Error: No such keg: /Users/tavelino/.brew/Cellar/php71**

So I tried to remove PHP 71

```
brew remove --force --ignore-dependencies httpd
...  Uninstalling httpd... (1,625 files, 27.2MB)

brew remove --force --ignore-dependencies php70-xdebug php71-xdebug

brew remove --force --ignore-dependencies php70-imagick php71-imagick

brew remove --ignore-dependencies --force php70 php71
```

Doesn't uninstall PHP71. And I have no idea what's going on

So I tried to install php72

```
brew install httpd php72
  ... 
  To have launchd start php@7.2 now and restart at login:
  brew services start php@7.2
  Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  php-fpm
```

Then I also runned

```
brew install php72 --with-httpd --with-thread-safety
```

Now if I check the version:

```
php -v
```

It still PHP 71
**PHP 7.1.33 (cli) (built: Jan 26 2020 22:52:32) ( NTS )**

So I am trying to find a way to change the version.

Comment: What have you tried to check how PHP 7.1 was installed?

Answer (score 1):

@Thais Avelino, I believe this sounds more like a `PATH` issue.

Below is basically what I did

- `brew install php@7.2`, php7.2 is under an version alias now
- `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`, this might be a step for your case
- `source ~/.bash_profile` to apply the change

```
$ php --version
PHP 7.2.31 (cli) (built: May 28 2020 23:54:50) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.31, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

$ ls -al $(which php)
-r-xr-xr-x  1 rchen  staff  13912836 Jul  4 16:33 /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/bin/php
```

Let me know if that works out, also attach `brew --version` and `brew config` if you still run into any issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with the positioning of your php path. Try moving it to the beginning.

i.e. like so...

```
PATH="/usr/local/php5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin: ...etc.
```

I used `packagephp-osx.liip.ch` package to upgrade to 7.3. It creates php5 alias for the folder with version 7.3, hence php5 in the PATH.
Terminal kept showing older version (7.1.33) until I modified the PATH.